# Animating text along an circular path with svg & javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, path, snap.svg

I'm trying to figure out how to make my text continuously loop along a circular path using http://snapsvg.io. I've been able to make it move along the path, but it stops once it gets to the end.

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/12x6q368/

```
<svg id="svgout" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 960 560" style="enable-background:new 0 0 960 560;" xml:space="preserve"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
</svg>

<script>
 var s = Snap("#svgout"); 

 var path = "M830.3,379.4c-17.2,73.3-202.5,92.4-413.8,42.7S48,272.7,65.2,199.4 s202.5-92.4,413.8-42.7S847.6,306.2,830.3,379.4z";

 var text = s.text(1000,50,'Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.')
    .attr({ 'textpath': path })
    .textPath.animate({ 'startOffset': -2000 }, 4000 );
</script>
```

I'm open to using other libraries too if necessary.

Comment: take a look here, maybe help you.  http://jonibologna.com/svg-text-along-a-path/ and http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-animate-object-path-repeat

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really an easy way to do what you want.  SVG 1.1* doesn't treat closed paths as continuous.  There is no way to make it automatically loop round to the start of the path.

The only way to do it I can think of is to have two or more versions of your path. Each of which has a different path start point.  Then when the text gets close to looping around to the start point, switch it across to the other path.

** SVG 2 (which is still in development) does treat closed paths as continuous.  So in the future, this won't be a problem.*

Comment: Thanks Paul. This was really helpful. I ended up just animating the svg text with CSS. much simpler, haha.